# IntelliMouse Optical USB and PS/2 Compatible Mouse no longer recognized

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, hp-pavilion, intellimouse

My wired IntelliMouse used to work fine on my HP Pavilion Notebook running Windows 10, but no longer does. I get the following error:

> The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.

...along with a recommendation box that tells me to reconnect the device.

I have tried reconnecting, as well as uninstalling the driver, disabling and enabling the driver, Power Options, Troubleshooting, Every single option in `devmgmt.msc`, but nothing works.

How can I fix this?

Comment: First, turn off Fast Startup (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) and then Restart, in the hope that a clean boot might help find the driver. If that doesn't help, in a CMD prompt as Administrator, run "SFC /scannow" to check system files (may take an hour or so).

Comment: Thanks. After running SFC /scannow, how do I know if something is wrong?

Comment: Read the log, as shown in the dialog. See https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-use-sfc-scannow-to-repair-windows-system-files-2626161